# Kubernetes installation on centos7

Tags: docker, kubernetes, centos7

I have a centos 7 server and I installed docker-ce(17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87).
When I tried to install kubernetes, I keep getting below conflict. docker-1.12.6-32.git88a4867.el7.centos.x86_64 dependency has been installed during docker-ce installation. If I uninstall docker-ce , I am able to install kubernetes. I am not able to install docker-ce and kubernetes on a machine because of this conflict.

I uninstalled docker and reinstalled it, but no luck. Please help me with this

```
---> Package docker-client.x86_64 2:1.12.6-32.git88a4867.el7.centos will be installed
---> Package docker-common.x86_64 2:1.12.6-32.git88a4867.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: docker-ce-17.06.0.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts docker
--> Processing Conflict: docker-ce-17.06.0.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts docker-io
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: docker-ce conflicts with 2:docker-1.12.6-32.git88a4867.el7.centos.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

FYI: I already tried yum remove docker docker-engine docker-selinux container-selinux and installed kubernetes. But this method is not allowing me to do anything in container. Yum update in ubuntu container is throwing error. I am also getting error in nginx container, centos container.

EG: When I ran command apt-get update, I keep getting error "E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
"

I executed command as root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/#installing-docker), Kubernetes is not yet compatible with docker-ce (docker >=17.x):

> On each of your machines, install Docker. Version 1.12 is recommended, but v1.10 and v1.11 are known to work as well. Versions 1.13 and 17.03+ have not yet been tested and verified by the Kubernetes node team.

Comment: So I need to uninstall docker-ce and install docker version 1.12 and then proceed with kubernetes installation right>

Comment: I think so, yes.

Comment: 1.13 seems to work without problems. 17.x fails because version parsing in kubelet does not support the new version layout.

Answer (score 0):

From the changelog at https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#external-dependency-version-information:

> Docker versions 1.10.3, 1.11.2, 1.12.6 have been validated

As of Kubernetes 1.7, Docker 17.xx are not supported. You'll need to uninstall Docker CE and let the Kubernetes installation instructions you are following install Docker 1.12 for you.

Comment: So I need to uninstall docker-ce and install docker and proceed with kubernetes installation?

Comment: How are you installing Kubernetes? Most solutions handle it for you.

Comment: using yum install kubernetes

Comment: Yum should handle this for you. It is already trying to install Docker as a dependency of `kubernetes` package. If you installed any extra Docker yum configuration then you may need to remove it.

Comment: Worked. Thanks :)